# Object.observe does not always gives me the right deleted index on an Array

Tags: javascript, object.observe

I have a list with an observer function  on it :

```
var names = ['joe', 'bob', 'loic'];

Object.observe(names, function(changes){
    changes.forEach(function(change) {        
      console.log(change.type, change.name)
    });
    console.log("names",names);
});   


console.log("######## del bob");
names.splice(1,1);// output is "update 1 - delete 2", why?
console.log("names", names) // but "bob" is the one deleted in the list
```

The deleted index according to the change object is 2, but I'm deleted the index 1, and the list has actually the index 1 deleted. Do you know why?

Is it because index 1 is updated to get index 2 value and index 2 is deleted?
Is there a way to get the actual deleted element index?

Comment: Deleting an element does not mean that all the following elements are shifted down. If you did `delete names[1]` you would just get a single `delete` message, and the array would contain `['joe', undefined, 'loic']`

Comment: Yep, it's because [how `.splice` works internally](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.12). It will first overwrite (update) the elements of the array and then remove them.

Comment: Thanks, using delete it works! :) (JS neewbie inside)

Comment: Maybe you could use Array.observe instead?

Comment: Well, `delete` leaves a hole in the array, which is usually not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a splice event at the right index with Array.observe :

```
var names = ['joe', 'bob', 'loic'];

Array.observe(names, function(changes){
    changes.forEach(function(change) {        
      console.log(change.type, change.name);
    });
});
```

Thanks @xavier-delamotte :)